# Rails continues to cache when the value is nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Rails 3.2.13 cache key for when the value is nil.  Have been looking at docs to find if there are any options to set to stop this behavior, but couldn't find any.

Is there anyway to stop Rails from caching a key when the value is nil?

```
1.8 :001 > value = nil
 => nil 
1.8 :002 > Rails.cache.fetch('foo'){value}
 => nil 
1.8 :003 > value = true
 => true 
1.8 :004 > Rails.cache.fetch('foo'){value}
 => nil
```

Comment: Don't know how to stop it, but quite often this is desirable behaviour. You may be used to behaviour of lightweight local caching e.g.  `@var ||= method` which uses uninitialised value of `nil` to stand in for "not cached yet", but that approach cannot cache `nil` or `false` values. A more general cache *should* cache `nil` and `false` values - and this is useful if those values have a high cost to calculate

Answer (score 3):

There is not in-build option in Rails cache to do that, so I would use a custom method to accomplish what you want, like the following:

```
def fetch(key, value)
  if Rails.cache.exist?(key)
    Rails.cache.read(key)
  else 
    Rails.cache.write(key, value) unless value.nil?
  end
end

fetch('foo', nil)
# => nil
fetch('foo', true)
# => true
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure to understand what's the problem, nil values will be ignored :

```
Rails.cache.fetch('foo') { nil }
Cache read: foo
Cache generate: foo
Cache write: foo
 => nil 

Rails.cache.fetch('foo'){ "bar" }
Cache read: foo
Cache generate: foo
Cache write: foo
 => "bar" 

Rails.cache.fetch('foo'){ nil }
Cache read: foo
Cache fetch_hit: foo
 => "bar"
```

Comment: I think you answer is wrong: `Rails.cache.exist?('foo')
# => true`

Comment: Yes nil values are cached, what i meant is that next value will still be written.

Answer (score 0):

Updated answer: `cache_nils` option is what you're looking for. Check the cache store you're using in case it doesn't support it, but for `dalli_store` works:

```
1.8 :001 > value = nil
 => nil 
1.8 :002 > Rails.cache.fetch('foo'){ value }
 => nil 
1.8 :003 > value = true
 => true 
1.8 :004 > Rails.cache.fetch('foo', cache_nils: false){ value }
 => true
```

Comment: It's probably an option of a specif cache store and not from ActiveSupport's base cache store.